# Can I crawl websites, download specific pages, and save rendered versions as PDFs in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, web-crawler

I just need some clarity here on whether this concept is possible or whether i have misunderstood what is capable of crawlers.

Say 1 have a list of 100 websites/blogs and every day, my program ( i am assuming its a crawler thingy )  will crwal thru them and if there is a match for some specified phrases like "miami heat" or "lebron james", it will proceed to download that page -> convert it to a pdf with full text/images and save that pdf.

So my questions are;

1. This type of thing is possible right ? Pls note that i dont want just text snippets but i am hoping to get the entire page as if it was printed out on a piece of paper?
2. This type of programs are called as crawlers right ?
3. i am planning to build on  code from http://phpcrawl.cuab.de/about.html

Comment: I'm sure someone else will give a full explanation but yes perfectly possible.

Comment: Most crawlers I believe are physical applications written in Java or C/C++. You may want to look into writing one in one of those languages. Also, remember to take care of and be mindful of the information you are retrieving. After all, downloading someone's page that they have put together may infringe upon copyrights and their intellectual property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly possible, as you are going to use phpcrawl to crawl the web pages use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert your html to pdf as it is

1. Yes it is possible, by using wkhtmltopdf tool you can convert web page as it is. its a desktop bases s/w so you can install in in you machine
2. Yes Crawlers.
3. Its a perfect tool for building what you want to build.

Comment: @bumperbox : its very good tool, we can use to on command line, these types of tools basically uses browsers to fetch html reder that html and convert it to image or pdf.

Comment: Just curious, do you know of any good cmd line application for printing pdfs to printer. Acroboat reader is not suitable as it shows a dialog?

Comment: try this command --- lpr -P "printer name" file.pdf  ----  not sure whether it will print formatted pdf or not

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I am using windows server

Comment: Sorry but I don't know much about windows.

Comment: Thanks pankaj. Will try wkhtmltopdf out

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is possible.
2. You could call it a crawler or a scraper, as you are scraping data off the websites.

Rendering the website to a PDF will probably be the hardest part, their are webservices that can do this for you.

For Example

http://pdfmyurl.com/

(I have no affiliation, and I have never used them, it was just the first site in the google results when I checked)